# Can't create a process on a remote machine using WMI?

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

I'm having some troubles getting a program to start on another machine on my network. Both machines are running Windows 10 Home.

Here is my full code: (The username and password have been removed for sharing purposes, but I'm logging on as the user the remote PC is logged into. The user has administrator.)

```cs
string serverName = "SERVER";
string processPath = @"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Streamer.bot-x64-0.1.19\Streamer.bot.exe";

// Credentials
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Username = "username";
options.Password = "password";

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope($@"\\{serverName}\root\cimv2", options);

ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass($@"\\{serverName}\root\cimv2:Win32_Process");
ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");

inParams["CommandLine"] = processPath;

// Start the process
ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
uint processId = (uint)(outParams["processId"]);

Debug.WriteLine($"Process started with ID: {processId}");

// Check the result
uint returnValue = (uint)(outParams["ReturnValue"]);
if (returnValue == 0)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Process started successfully on the remote server.");
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to start process. Return code: {returnValue}");
}
```

The result was a return value of 0, indicating the process should've started, but it doesn't.

I tried executing a basic program by changing `CommandLine` and adding `CurrentDirectory`:

```cs
inParams["CommandLine"] = "calc.exe";
inParams["CurrentDirectory"] = @"c:\windows\system32";
```

The result was the same as the last time, return value of 0 but the process didn't start.

To my knowledge, the correct permissions have been set up on the remote PC, as I was getting "Access denied" errors, but I am no longer receiving those. The remote PC has been restarted since these changes have been made.

Any help on this would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Assuming the Account (whatever that is) has been configured (using wmimgmt.msc or wmic on the remote machine) to allow the execution of processes, you can start a process non-interactive. I.e., without user interface. Check the TaskManager of the remote machine, to verify whether the process is listed there -- You may want to test [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

Comment: If the process has a UI you also need the session logged in. Can be locked but has to be logged in